# Is there a way to retrieve my previous commands on Ubuntu?

Tags: history

I was doing an assignment on Ubuntu that requires screenshots of my commands. But my laptop shut down and the program closed without me taking the screenshots. Is there a way to retrieve my previous commands on Ubuntu?

Comment: check your bash history file - maybe u r lucky. `less ~/.bash_history`

Comment: There is a command for that ---->    `history`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find them in `~/.bash_history`.

Note that `~/` refers to your home folder.

The full path would be, `/home/<your-username>/.bash_history`

Answer (score 0):

It addition to what others have said here, if you want to see them one at a time, just press the up-arrow key when you are in your terminal. This will display them one at a time. (Hitting enter will re-execute the command, as well.)